# Which user can use setpgid() function?

Tags: c, linux

I worked out the function for the setpgid() when i executing this function the result will be permission denied. then i logged in as a root user that time also this will print the error message as permission denied. then which user can use this function. Can anyone explain to me?

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<unistd.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>

  main()
   {
    printf("parent pid=%d\tpgid=%d\n",getpid(),getpgid(getpid()));
    pid_t pid,pgid;
    pgid=getpgid(getpid());
    if((pid=fork())==0)
    {
            printf("befor sessionchild pid=%d\tpgid=%d\n",getpid(),getpgid(getpid()));
            sleep(5);
            pid_t p;
            printf("child pid=%d\tpgid=%d\n",getpid(),getpgid(getpid()));
            if((p=fork())==0){
                    sleep(2);
                    setsid();
                    printf("child2 pid=%d\tpgid=%d\n",getpid(),getpgid(getpid()));
                    setpgid(getpid(),pgid);
                    perror("Error");
                    printf("after setting group id child2 pid=%d\tpgid=%d\n",getpid(),getpgid(getpid()));
            }
            wait(0);
            exit(0);
    }
    exit(0);
  }
```

Comment: I am not quite sure, but maybe something related to session id?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you really need to check the return value of your function calls before you call `perror()`, otherwise you don't know which of your calls that failed - it might not been the most recent call before your `perror()` statement that failed. The code should be something like:

```
if (setpgid(getpid(),pgid) != 0) {
    perror("setpgid");
}
```

If it really is setpgid() that fails, here's what the [docs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setpgid.2.html) says:

> **EPERM**  An  attempt  was  made  to move a process into a process group
>   in a different session, or to change the process group ID of one of
>   the children of the calling process and the child was in a different
>                 session, or to change the process group ID of a session leader (setpgid(), setpgrp()).

So it sounds like you are hitting this first case described since your child process calls `setsid()`.

The glibc docs about [job control](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Job-Control.html) has a bit of reading material on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you should do error handling.

Check the *return value* of **every** API call, looking for errors.

*If* (and only if) an error occoured, then you should check `errno` and use `perror`.